# Who are these two girl figures?

Tags: merchandise

I am trying to identify these girls for a friend. Any lead would be most appreciated.

[image: Figure 1]
[image: Figure 2]

Comment: Welcome to the Anime/Manga SE. In the event that you suspect the figures might be from different sources, you should post two separate questions.

Comment: The first one looks like from Fortune Arterial. The second one I don't know, but definitely not from the same series. You should follow Maroon's advice and make a separate question.

Comment: yes 1st one is Erika sendou from Fortune Arterial and while asking try to add picture like the 1st one , where more detail are visible

Comment: You should check the figure (like on the bottom/base) for any markings such as the copyright. I will help in find details such as the maker or series.

Comment: As nhahtdh and mirroroftruth said, the first figure is Erika Sendou from Fortune Arterial. The piece of paper in the background appears to have the logo of Fortune Arterial on it, so you could have figured that one out by Googling for "Fortune Arterial".

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it does not include the minimum required information for identification. Please refer to our recent ruling on Image-based Identification request for more information http://meta.anime.stackexchange.com/questions/2736/image-only-id-request-cleanup?cb=1

Answer (score 5):

As @Alchemist already pointed out the first figurine is [Erika Sendou](http://www.anisearch.com/character/15952,erika-sendou) from the anime series [Fortune Arterial](http://www.anisearch.com/anime/6277,fortune-arterial).

[image]

The second figurine is a swimsuit version of the character [Al Azif](http://www.anisearch.com/character/13471,aru-ajifu) from the anime/game [Kishin Houkou Demonbane](http://www.anisearch.com/anime/607,kishin-houkou-demonbane-2006).

[image]

Answer (score 4):

The first one is Erika Sendou from Fortune Arterial.

[image: Erika Sendou]